# How to Hide default Authentication Providers in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, powershell, sharepoint-server

I am using Claim Provider authentication and I tried to hide default authentication provider based from People picker using powershell. I copied the following powershell script from Steve Peschka blog however it will hide AD result on Farm Level (all zone) not only in People Picker. Is there any to resolve this without a need to extend web application.

```
$cpm = Get-SPClaimProviderManager
$ad = get-spclaimprovider -identity "AD"
$ad.IsVisible = $false
$cpm.Update()
```

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2011/05/07/hiding-default-authentication-providers-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: what you mean by hide everywhere? did you reset IIS?

Comment: sorry, i mean it will hide on farm level not in specific people picker functionality. I will update the question. thx